# fixing excess spaces in a text file

Tags: replace, terminal, output, removing-whitespace

I have output from a program called KRAKEN that looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMgnu.png) (also I apologize for the link but i couldn't figure out how to put tabs within a line into markdown because they just get converted to spaces)

So the problem with this is pretty obvious because if I want to do any type of text editing in terminal, these spaces equal tabs which equal new columns. What I have been trying to do is delete all of these spaces and essentially justify the 6 column.

Currently I have tried using the column command which almost worked but my output looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyXje.png)

So now I have more columns than I need. So another potential fix could be to combine all the columns after column 6 but I do not know how to do this either.

The goal is to get the output to look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8Gzn.png)

So a quick tldr:

1. Is there any way to remove excess spaces and justify only one column in a text file?
2. Or is there a way to combine columns after a certain column yet keep the rows seperate?

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix for this if anyone has an issue with this type of output. 
so starting from the original file called test.txt.

```
column -t test.txt > temp1.txt
awk '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6" "$7" "$8" "$9}' temp1.txt > final.txt
```

For reference test.txt looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhkT4.png), temp1.txt looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MW5DP.png) and the final.txt looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmT99.png).